# How to check multiple files for duplicates in C++

Tags: c++, linux, duplicates, md5sum

I need to compare 5 files by their file paths: a,b,c,d,e and find duplicates if exists.
How can I do this in c++ via md5sum comparison of files?

Comment: Why do you need `md5sum`? [This duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750409/do-we-have-any-method-approach-of-removing-duplicate-files-using-boost-filesyste/21750953#21750953) concludes that you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to compute a checksum for each file (write it yourself or call an external program), get hold of each file, ... This depends on the operating system. It is much easier to do something like this in a scripting language.

Comment: I have to use c/c++ library for computing the ckecksums

Comment: can you use `popen()` to run the `md5sum` command and read its output?